# Couldn't you use maven + spring to create a global repository and reduce duplicate libraries and/or deployment complexity?

Tags: java, spring, maven, dependencies

So one of the problems with Java is that you wind up with duplicate libraries on the same system. Now that we have products like maven, I've been wondering why this still needs to be the case. For example, one might have a central final release-only repo for all running java applications on a particular machine or a particular application server. For app servers, if you created a singular dependency on something that handles dependencies programmatically, perhaps through a maven-like mechanism in the Spring configuration, couldn't you have all of your dependencies just handled auto-magically?  If it couldn't be done in the Spring configuration, then perhaps the container could be extended? I suppose the trick might be building the Classpath but that really doesn't seem insurmountable. Especially since the top 3 OS's now all have symbolic links. Haven't looked in quite a while but it appears there is now a way to handle and/or create them in Java:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/links.html

Of course symbolic links might even be overkill.

I suppose what I am asking is, couldn't you use these ideas to greatly simplify dependency management or deployment for all Java SE / Java EE applications?

Comment: It is not clear for me, what de-duplication are you talking about? Jars across Maven repositories in your organization? I think HDD space is so cheap, that nobody cares about that: your time to eliminate the duplication will cost more then the disk space you will gain.

Comment: Agreed - it sounds like the OP is proposing a solution that will have worse consequences (complexity, fragility, slower startup) than the problem that he/she wants to solve.  Not to mention, that it is not clear what that problem really is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this article:

http://www.infoq.com/news/2009/06/jigsaw

In summary, these ideas are part of Java 7. The JVM will have a dependency management sub-component called Jigsaw and the new requires keyword to grab what it needs.

Answer (score 0):

IBM WebSphere certainly has a feature called **shared libraries** where you can make a library entity and then import it in multiple projects. In Oracle Weblogic you can probably deploy as library or add paths to your `weblogic-application.xml`. I dont think using maven would be necessary.

Comment: Well that depends on if you also have Tomcat running on the same machine or if there are some libraries that are also used by JSE applications. The objective is that if there is a library available on the hard drive, it should be available to any application that needs it without redundancy.

Comment: sry I couldn't get the full breadth of your question

Answer (score 0):

Containers like [equinox](http://eclipse.org/equinox/) and [felix](http://felix.apache.org/site/index.html) support a standard called [OSGi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSGi), which extends dependency management into the realm of deployment.

In a nutshell, one releases a "bundle" that states your package's run-time dependencies and the container will ensure that version is running (more efficient than the J2EE container's approach of isolated classloaders)

Real problem with OSGi is lack of adoption. Tooling has improved but Sun (now Oracle) never embraced it as part of J2EE. The [jigsaw](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/) appears to be the "great white hope" and I'll be honest in that I have not been following the OSGi versus Jisaw debate, recently.

In conclusion, extending dependency management into the area of deployment is a great idea, but requires container support. OSGi is the closest we have to a standard.

Comment: So if it is container dependent, which naturally implies a container is required, why not use one J2SE Spring container (Extended perhaps?) per individual machine. This container puts all the required libraries in one place so that applications and application servers have only one place to look for required libraries.

Comment: Why re-invent the wheel? OSGI and Jigsaw are already one solution too many in this area :-)